# Forgot Password sending to Email in Android

Tags: android, email

I'm developing an app now with a forgot password in it. In able to access the full feature of the system, the user must login first. When the user click the Forgot Password, it goes to the Forgot Password Activity. In that activity, there's an EditText for email address and a Send button. What I'd like to happen is that, when the user fill-out the email address EditText and click the Send Button, the password will automatically be sent to the email inputted by the user. How can I code it in Android?

Comment: from where do you intend to sent the password to email. From server?

Comment: Two points: 1) where is your code so far? how much have you gotten to? 2) never store passwords on any server or storage devices any where for any reason. It is a bad security issue.

Comment: @Raghunandan, nope. From database itself.

Comment: @LuckyMe, I actually don't have codes so far since I don't know how to start.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Where is this database running? On the Android device? And what does this password protect? Which application running where does then check if the email address matches a valid user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi RanmaMarquee,

In this code contain what you asked. its working perfect. but, you must change your mail id and password there (duplicated given FROM) and give TO mail id without fail. (In this program you will get new password from database or somewhere, and attached it to mail id) and here when we click forget password button, it will go to new activity and then, you enter your mail and click send button. It will send mail to Recipient side.

Note: dont forget to give from mail id and password and TO mail id in program..

http://www.mediafire.com/download/4mf3j3d6w4kalxd/Text_Email_Sending.zip

Comment: You should inline the code in the answer. Links dies from time to time.

Comment: @harikrishnan, thank you so much for your help however it's not working to me. And I'd like to clarify, in the EditText, the user will input Email Address not the mail itself.

Comment: @RanmaMarquee,i think you may not understand my code. First thing @ did you give the email id and password from that specified line. and to email id also. why because, already i checked my self and give it to you.

Comment: If I want to retrieve password from MySQL , then send to e-mail, will it works ?